# Running Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with changing proposal kernel; each time the kernel is changing starting the algorithm afresh. Does it work?

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

I have a Markov kernel $Q$ from which I would like to generate proposals for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm. The problem is: When the proposal is accepted, the "internal state" of $Q$ changes. This means that if proposals $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ are accepted, the internal state of $Q$ depends on $y_1,\ldots,y_n$. I know, this means that we cannot use $Q$ as a proposal kernel for the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.

However, my simple solution to that problem is the following: Before the first sample is accepted, the state of $Q$ does not change. Now, I simply run the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with proposal kernel $Q$ **until** the first proposal is accepted. Then I stop. Then I start the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm again, but with the different proposal kernel given by the modified kernel $Q$.

Is this process still guaranteed to work? Are the accepted samples distributed according to the target density after a sufficient long period of time?

**EDIT**:

I think we can describe the algorithm I've got in mind as follows:

- Let $E$ be the state space and $Q_k$ be a Markov kernel with source $E^k$ and target $E$
- Start with any $x_0\in E$
- Run Metropolis-Hastings with initial state $x_0$ and proposal kernel $Q_1$ for a single iteration
- Let $y_1\in E$ denote the proposed sample and $x_2\in E$ the state after the iteration (So, $x_1=y_1$ if the proposal was accepted and $x_1=x_0$ otherwise)
- Now run Metropolis-Hastings with initial state $x_1$ and proposal kernel $Q_2(x_0,y_1,\;\cdot\;)$ (remark: I'm unsure whether it wouldn't be better to replace this with $Q_2(x_0,x_1,\;\cdot\;)$)
- and so on ...

It would be interesting to know whether - under certain assumptions on $Q_1,Q_2,\ldots$ - the samples $x_b,x_{b+1},\ldots$ are still distributed according to the target density for sufficiently large $b$.

### **EDIT 2**

You can assume that $Q_k(x_1,\ldots,x_k;\;\cdot\;)$ has density $$q_k(x_1,\ldots,x_k;\;\cdot\;):=e^{-\beta f_k(x_1,\ldots,x_k;\;\cdot\;)}$$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1)^d$, where $f_k(x_1,\ldots,x_k;\;\cdot\;)$ is nonnegative. Also: The $Q_i$ are constructed in a way so that at the last iteration $k_{\text{max}}$, we have $f_{k_{\text{max}}}(x_1,\ldots,x_{k_{\text{max}}})=0$. So, the sequence $Q_1,\ldots,Q_{k_{\text{max}}}$ somehow converges; maybe this is enough to show that everything works.

Comment: I'd be interested to know how this problem came about!

Comment: @jbowman It is important for me that the spectrum of the generated proposals have a certain profile. In order to ensure that, I need to minimize some kind of "energy" induced by the previously generated points and the new proposal. (But the locations of the previously generated samples are not altered during this minimization step.)

Comment: So, if I've followed you, which I may well not have, you are updating the proposal as you learn more about the distribution - which would, in the long run, lead to higher, perhaps much higher, acceptance probabilities?

Comment: @jbowman "*you are updating the proposal as you learn more about the distribution*" ... The target distribtion? No. It is actually quite simple: For a set of $k$ vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_k$, we have an energy $E(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$. The proposal scheme works as follows: Given $x_0$, generate new proposals according to $e^{-E(x_0,\;\cdot\;)/T}$, where $T>0$. Once a proposal is accepted, call it $x_1$, we formally restart MH, but this time we generate new proposals according to $e^{-E(x_0,\:x_1,\;\cdot\;)/T}$. And so on.

Comment: @jbowman The question is: Does this work (i.e. can I build asymptotically unbiased estimators from the generated samples)? Maybe https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-7/issue-2/An-adaptive-Metropolis-algorithm/bj/1080222083.full is the answer to that question, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Is the update of energy after each acceptance Markovian?

Comment: @jbowman Yes, when a proposal is accepted, we stop the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, add the accepted proposal to the internal state of the proposal kernel $Q$ and then run Metropolis-Hastings again, but with the modified proposal kernel. Hopefully it is quite clear from my latest edit to the question.

Comment: When you calculate your acceptance probability, are you using the existing kernel for the "reverse" transition probability calculation or the kernel that will be adopted if the proposal is accepted? If the latter, I think you're good, but the former would seem to me to mess up reversability.

Comment: ... to add to the comment, if you go from (state A, kernel a) to (state B, kernel b), can you make the reverse transition back to (state A, kernel a) or do you get a different kernel?

Comment: @jbowman Say we are in iteration $i$ and the previously proposed values are $y_1,\ldots,y_{i-1}$. Then I'm sampling the proposal $y_i$ from $\rho_i(y):=\exp(-\beta f_i(y))$, where $\beta$ is a parameter controlling the influence of $f_i$ and $$f_i(y)=\int_{[0,\:1)^n}\left|g_{y}(z)-\left(h(z)-\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}g_{y_j}(z)\right)\right|\:{\rm d}z.$$ In the next iteration - no matter whether $y_i$ is accepted or not - the proposal is taken from $\rho_{i+1}$, where the involved $y_i$ is the previously proposed sample.

Comment: @jbowman The reason why I need to do is, is that I need to ensure that all samples contributing to the final estimate follow a specific spatial arrangement. I'm using a waste-recycling estimator (so all proposed values contribute) and so the proposal densities $\rho_i$ ensure that this is the case. Maybe it would be better to not use waste-recycling and construct $\rho_i$ differently so that it is defined in the same way, but only with the accepted proposals involved. What do you think?

Comment: @jbowman Regarding the proposal density in the definition of the acceptance probability: I guess we can write $$\tilde f_i(a,b):=\int_{[0,\:1)^n}\left|g_{a}(z)+g_{b}(z)-\left(h(z)-\sum_{j=1}^{i-2}g_{y_j}(z)\right)\right|\:{\rm d}z$$ and then use $\tilde\rho_i(a,b):=\exp(-\beta f_i(a,b))$ as the proposal density? The problem here might be that $y_{i-1}$ does not need to be equal to the current state (i.e. the last accepted state ...) ... (But $\tilde\rho_i$ is obviously symmetric and hence cancels out in the acceptance probability)

Comment: @jbowman The latter problem is the reason why I've simply considered the proposal kernel as being independent of the current state. However, then its density value does not cancel out anymore in the definition of the acceptance probability and I think the value $\rho_i(x_i)$, where $x_i$ is the current state, does not really make sense? ($g_{x_i}$ is then also counted twice in the definition of $\rho_i$)

Comment: @jbowman So, to really specifically answer your question: If we use the proposal density $\rho_{i+1}$ (or $\tilde\rho_{i+1}$) for computation of $\rho_{i+1}(x_i)$ (i.e. the "reverse transition probability"), I don't know if this would really make sense for the same reason; since, again, $g_{x_i}$ is counted twice ... but I don't know whether this is a problem or not, but I can tell you that this will increase the value of $f_i$ and hence decrease the value of $\rho_i$ ... BUT BTW: aren‘t there non-reversible MH variants? Maybe we don’t need reversibility

Comment: Are you restarting everytime with the same $x_0$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus What do mean by "everytime"? Once, when the whole process is started, I choose one $x_0$ (uniformly from my domain, which is $[0,1)^d$ in my application).

Comment: @0xbadf00d *"Then I start the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm again,"* What does that mean? Does it mean that you stop computing the random walk already after the first step and re-start at the beginning point $x_0$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus No, what I mean is that I restart the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with the new proposal kernel. The initial state is the last accepted state from one of the previous runs.

Comment: And how is that solution different from the situation of not restarting the algorithm? What do you mean by 'restart'?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I simply mean that I now run the algorithm with a different proposal kernel. A generalization of this would be: Select $x_0$. Run MH with initial state $x_0$ and proposal kernel $Q_1$ for one iteration. Let $x_1$ denote the state after the first iteration. Now, abort and run a new instance of MH with initial state $x_1$ and proposal kernel $Q_2$. And so, on. In my case, $Q_{i+1}$ depends on the proposed states $y_0,\ldots,y_i$ (but I'm willing to modify it so that only depends on the accepted states $x_0,\ldots,x_i$).

Comment: And how would you do it without 'restart'. I don't get the difference or what you mean by 'a new instance of MH'. *"However, my simple solution to that problem is the following:"* what is the difference between your solution and the other process? In the other case you would not run multiple 'instances of MH'?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Effectively, the only thing which happens is that the proposal distribution changes after each iteration. That's it. What I wrote about "restarting" is more or less a formal problem: The proposal should be a distribution which only depends on the current state of the chain. But in my case, it depends on the whole history.

Comment: *"the proposal distribution changes after each iteration"* and how is this different between the situations with and without your solution?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus It is not; it is just philosophical to circumvent the formal problem that my $Q_i$ does not only depend on a single state.

Comment: So briefly stated your question is about running MH while changing the kernel after each accepted proposal and in particular the kernel is dependent on all past accepted values instead of only the current accepted value...

Comment: ... your question is when this version of MH is applicable. Obviously it doesn't work in general, but the counter question is why would you like to do it in this way? Is it to speed up the burn in period or to make transitions to far away locations more likely?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus I just wanted to write this: I don't want to ruin things by being too general. My guess is that we need some kind of convergence of $(Q_k)$. Please take a look at my edit 2, where I'm more specific about my actual setting. (I don't know whether you read the comments, but there you can find an even more specific version of $f_k$ and see that I'm also unsure whether I should only consider accepted or every proposals).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus You've also asked why I'm doing this: I need to ensure that the set of all samples contributing to the estimate that I want to compute using this samples satisfies a certain spectral property (i.e. the Fourier spectrum of that point set needs to satisfy a property). My proposal kernels ensure this. This construction is the reason why it's also important to decide whether we use waste-recycling or not. Since in the former case, every proposal does contribute.

Comment: *"You can assume that $Q_k(x_1,\ldots,x_k;\;\cdot\;)$ has density $$q_k(x_1,\ldots,x_k;\;\cdot\;):=e^{-\beta f_k(x_1,\ldots,x_k;\;\cdot\;)}$$... "* I don't understand this edit, how it is an assumption. $f_k$ can be anything.

Comment: So your application is a situation where you want to generate a sample from a distribution, but also with certain conditions satisfied. Can I see this as an analogy with the option `empirical` for [`mvrnorm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/MASS/html/mvrnorm.html), which constraints the sample to have the exact mean and covariance matrix as distribution parameters.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus The crucial point in the assumption is $f_{k_{\text{max}}}(x_1,\ldots,x_{k_{\text{max}}})=0$. However, as I wrote before, $f_k$ is more specifically of the form in the comments above. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with R and hence don't know what `mvrnorm` really is.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus You can imagine the following: The $g_{x_i}$ are kernels centered at $x_i$ and we want to place them so that $\sum_ig(x_i)$ is a $L^1$-norm approximation of the function $h$. The function $h$ is - in practice - a vague approximation of the target density $p$ of the MH algorithm. This construction ensures that the $x_i$ "follow the shape" of $p$ and hence are already close to be distributed according to $p$ (But don't get confused; the construction also ensures that the spectral property I'm interested in is satisfied; but that's too confusing here).

Comment: @0xbadf00d I had created a link out of the mvrnorm. It is a function to create a multivariate normal distributed sample. By using the option `empirical = TRUE` then the sample will have exactly the mean and covariance as the population mean and covariance (which is not happening in general, the mean of a sample $x_i \sim N(0,1)$ is typically different from zero).

Comment: *"the construction also ensures that the spectral property I'm interested in is satisfied"* This is an important detail. If you want your sample to satisfy a specific condition, and any typical random sample does not satisfy such condition, then by definition the algorithm doesn't 'work', because samples that only satisfy a specific condition are not samples from the target distribution, and instead samples from the target distribution with an additional constraint...

Comment: ...But the algorithm not working is by design. You *want* that the algorithm doesn't work. Or what is meant by 'working' should be redefined. It might be useful to explain this condition better in the question, because the straightforward answer is that the algorithm doesn't work.

Comment: *"The $Q_i$ are constructed in a way so that at the last iteration $k_{\text{max}}$, we have $f_{k_{\text{max}}}(x_1,\ldots,x_{k_{\text{max}}})=0$."* This is not entirely clear. If how is the $f_{k_{\text{max}}}(x_1,\ldots,x_{k_{\text{max}}}) = 0$ incorporated into $f_{k_{\text{max}}}(x_1,\ldots,x_{k_{\text{max}}}; \cdot)$?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus If the set of proposals satisfies a certain condition, doesn't the acceptance/rejection step in MH still ensure that the accepted proposals follow the target distribution?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus With "working" I simply mean that if $\mu$ is the target distribution and $(X_i)_i$ is the sequence of accepted proposals chain, we still got $\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(X_i)\to\mu f$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d if your method is constructed in such a way that certain samples are not able to be drawn because they do not satisfy a certain condition, then the sampling method does not generate samples that follow the target distribution. E.g. if your target distribution is $N(0,1)$ but your condition is that the sample satisfies $\bar{X} = 0$ then you only sample a subset from the distribution of potential samples.

Comment: Is it that your samples $X_i$ need to follow the target distribution or is it that their mean $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} X_i$ needs to follow the target distribution? With the MH-algorithm I imagine that you wish to generate a sample whose empirical density approaches the true density. (And with this last comment it seems that my example is actually not a good example. A sample with $\bar{X} = 0$ will have the empirical distribution approach the true standard Gaussian distribution when $n \to \infty$)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus (a) What if I ensure that the proposals $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,$ are "uniformly distributed in a Quasi-Monte Carlo sense; i.e. $\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^ng(Y_i)\to\int_{[0,\:1)^d}g$? Would this be enough?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus (b) I will now go into more detail: If [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TV8w.png) is our target density, then my proposal kernels ensure that the proposals "follow the shape" of the target density and remain a certain minimal distance to each other (but the samples are closer in regions where the target density is large). The proposal set looks then like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQAXg.png). And if the proposal density is constant, then the proposals look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6t4T.png).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Since the proposals are already close to the distribution of the target density, I was hoping that the MH acceptance/rejection methodology would ensure that $\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(X_i)\to\mu f$. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the proposed algorithm correctly, we can prove that this doesn't *generally* sample from the target distribution by way of counter example. And while this algorithm will be a bit pathological, I believe it does do a good job of illustrating what can easily go wrong with this method.

Consider the case that the target distribution is a N(0, 1) distribution. For $Q_1$, we select a N(0, 0.5) distribution. For $Q_2$, we select a N(0, 0.001) if $x_1$ was positive and N(0, 0.5) if $x_2$.

In the target distribution, 50% of the values should be positive. However, in our algorithm, if the current state becomes positive, it gets stuck in the positive region for a very long time due to the small step size. If the current state is negative, it moves quickly due to the large step size. Thus, the samples from our algorithm will be disporpotionally positive, even after sufficient burnin. Therefore, we never approach the target distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did you take a look into the comments? Does the situation change with the specific form of the proposal?

Comment: Also: Doesn't [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-7/issue-2/An-adaptive-Metropolis-algorithm/bj/1080222083.full) describe such an adaptive Metropolis-Hastings variant? It seems like that we might be able to show that the process obtained still has Ergodic properties; even when it is not Markov anymore.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: indeed adaptive MCMC is a valid approach. However, in the paper you've cited, they show that the proposal distribution converges which is key. In my pathological case, it does not. If I'm understanding your proposal, it doesn't seem like the proposal distribution will converge, in fact it will different _conditional on the current state_? This will require some non-trivial conditions to make work, although not impossible (e.g. Hamiltonian Monte Carlo).

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by claiming that the "proposal distribution does converge"? We have a sequence of proposal kernels $Q_k$; do you mean that there must be a kernel $Q$ so that $Q_k(x,\;\cdot\;)$ converges to $Q(x,\;\cdot\;)$ for all $x$? If so, in which sense must the convergence take place (weakly, total variation, ...)?

Comment: In the paper you cited, they mention how the covariance matrix eventually converges essentially as an approximation of the target function. If I understand your algorithm, the proposal function is dependent on the current state and we should not generally expect it to converge unless there are other stipulations I am missing?

Comment: Circling back to my pathological example, I think it's clear that it won't sample correctly from the target distribution since it slows down based on where it is on the target distribution. In your approach, can you show why this type of issue (i.e. slowing down resulting in over sampling of a region) wouldn't be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Given the large amount of comments I thought that it might be better when I place some of them in an answer.

What I understand from the comments following the question is that the idea is about performing some form of MCMC-sampling, but with a Kernel that adapts after each new sample. And, the motivation is to ensure that the sample will satisfy a certain condition.

#### Simple example

A simple example would be the sampling of a distribution symmetric around zero (e.g. a standard normal distribution) but with the constraint that the sample mean needs to be zero (typically, if the distribution has zero mean, a sample from it does not need to be zero).

If we have a kernel that proposes every time that the sample mean is unequal to zero a sample whose value makes the sample mean equal to zero. Then we ensure that this property is fulfilled (at least every odd step).

The set of samples that can be sampled will not be iid variables and will not be the same as sampling the target distribution without the constraint. However, if the target distribution is symmetric around zero, then this algorithm will generate a sample whose empirical distribution approaches the true distribution.

Below is a code example that has the proposed sample based on the complete history $$x^\star|x_0,x_1,\dots,x_t \sim \begin{cases} -\sum_{i=0}^t x_i & \qquad \text{if $\sum_{i=0}^t x_i \neq 0$} \\
N(x_t,0.04) & \qquad \text{if $\sum_{i=0}^t x_i = 0$} \\
\end{cases}$$

Below is an example of the histogram of a sample of size 50000 when the target function is a standard normal.

[image: example]

This sample is in not a typical sample from a normal distribution. The sample will be having zero mean with probability 1, whereas a sample from a normal distribution will be having zero mean with probability 0 (and also the samples will be relatively symmetric).

However, the empirical distribution will approach the the distribution function of the target distribution. So in that sense this sampling 'works'.

For different more complex cases it will depend. For example, when we use the method above with a non-symmetric distribution, then it stops 'working'.

```
set.seed(1)

newsample = function(old_sample, LikelihoodFunction) {
    L = length(old_sample)
    m = sum(old_sample)

    ### if the current sample has not zero mean then the suggestion will always be a sample that makes the mean zero
    if (m!=0) {
      suggest = -m
    } else {
      suggest = rnorm(1,old_sample[L],0.2)
    }

    ### compare the likelihood and base the next sample on it
    u = runif(1)
    l1 = LikelihoodFunction(suggest)
    l2 = LikelihoodFunction(old_sample[L])
    if (u<l1/l2) {
      return(suggest)
    } else {
      return(old_sample[L])
    }    
}

### start the mcmc in the point 0
sample = c(0)

### generate 50000 samples
for (i in 1:50000) {
   sample = c(sample, newsample(sample, LikelihoodFunction = function(x) {dnorm(x)}))
}

### plot histogram with curve for target density as comparison 
hist(sample, seq(-5,5,0.1), xlim =c(-3,3), freq = 0)
xs = seq(-4,4,0.01)
lines(xs, dnorm(xs))
```